# How to count and join between two MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, ifnull

I want to write out the number of times a car has been rented and I just cant get it to work, I have two tables. one is called `vehicle` and the other `rental`.

In rental is where all the "rentings" go when you book a car and all the vehicles is stored in vehicle. This is the query I made that almost works.

```
SELECT vehicle.id,COUNT(rental.vid) as rented,IFNULL(rental.vid,0) as nothing, vehicle.make as make, vehicle.model as model, vehicle.regnr as regnr, vehicle.color as color, vehicle.state as state, vehicle.imgurl as img, vehicle.description as description, vehicle.id 
FROM rental,vehicle 
WHERE vid = vehicle.id GROUP BY vid
```

and will print out this:

[image: The Tables it prints out]

The rest which doesn't have a value (never been rented) isn't there, I have tried a lot of different ways with `IFNULL` but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Downvote for stupid title.

Comment: Just so you know, readers appreciate effort in posts, so "wanna" and "thx" are not advisable. We tend to say that if typing real words is too much trouble, Stack Overflow maybe is not for you. The reason for this is that questions are not just for the poster here - they are for many future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` from `Vehicle` table and `Left Join` to `Rental` table.  This will include Vehicle that have never been Rented and their Count(rental.vid) will be 0:

```
SELECT vehicle.id
,COUNT(rental.vid) as rented
, vehicle.make as make
, vehicle.model as model
, vehicle.regnr as regnr
, vehicle.color as color
, vehicle.state as state
, vehicle.imgurl as img
, vehicle.description as description
FROM vehicle
left join rental on vid = vehicle.id 
GROUP BY vehicle.id
```

[Here is a simplified example](http://rextester.com/OKM24135)

The implicit join you have in your example is equivalent to an `inner join`.  With a left join you select all rows you want from your source table.   If there are matches to the table you are left joining to, they will appear as well.  It's a good way to append data to your source table.

Comment: some people are just to good at this, thx man really appreciate it

Comment: is it possible to filter out one car make if needed?

Comment: Im new to this site so i apologize for any inconvenience i may have caused, if title still is bad then i apologize again for that.

Comment: @fredan you are all good.  No inconvenience to me, it just helps other users gain benefit from these issues when they have similar problems